# Problem with knit Markdown file and pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to knit my R Markdown file.

> Error running filter C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua:
> cannot open C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua: No such file or directory
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
> Execution halted

RStudio and rmarkdown are installed and updated to lastest versions.

The file rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua exists, I checked.
No idea why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue and solved by setup coding saving encoding to UTF8.

1. The issue is related to your folder with non-english name.
2. if your operation system is setup to using utf-8. you can change your project level encoding to utf8 by following steps.

menu --> Tools--> project---> code editing --> Text encoding--> utf8

1. if you has not solve you need check you current Rstuiod encoding
   by > sessionInfo()  to the your R session encoding .
2. if may list.files('target_file_with_fullpath') to see if the file is exists or not. If you can it the target_file_with_fullpaht in your operation system, but not found in your R project session, pls double check sessionInfo() and change it to make sure both are same.

regarding how to change R sessionInfo() environment variable
, it is another topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, coding saving encoding to UTF8 did not help in solving my problem. However, I changed the username and user in the path to the file 'pagebreak.lua' (English encoding), and it works

Comment: glad to know you solve it. Recently, I have found another way to solve it as well similar to vscode. 
1. open file, and reopen it in another encoding   in menu file ---> reopen with encoding...
2. save the opened file in another encoding. in menu file ---> save with encoding

in this way, you can convert the file encoding.